# Pages rendering differently in Google Chrome and FireFox

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome

I'm trying to figure out why the front page of my blog (http://www.ulblog.org) renders differently between Google Chrome and FireFox. It appears 'broken' in Google Chrome, but renders without issues in FireFox.

Other pages on the site, however, appear to render fine in both (stack overflow apparently will only allow me to include one link, so unable to provide link to a working page).

Any help appreciated!

Comment: try validating your code: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ulblog.org%2F you have 10 errors and a closing div is missing.

Comment: Thanks Kieran -- my problem is I can't for the life of me figure out where the unmatched div comes from. The other errors appear to be 'non-breaking', which doesn't mean that I won't spend time fixing them, just I'd like to get the basic rendering right, first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 238 you have `<p>&nbsp;</p`. It should be `<p>&nbsp;</p>` (i.e. you're missing an end angle bracket.)

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the answer!

Answer (score 0):

(seems broken in my Firefox 3.6)

Replace the `margin-left` on your `#sidebar` with a `float: left`.

Remove the `sidebar` div from `#maincontent` and place it below it rather than within it.

This should fix most of your Chrome related issues (and FF for me).

Oh. As stated by @Kieran, try validating your code.

Comment: Apolgies Russell, the fact that it was broken in FF3.6 may well be because I took a stab at a fix and it made it broken in both. I'm rendering now in 3.6 and it's back to working there, still not working in Chrome.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are setting such an extreme margin left for your sidebar? when giving it a `float: left;` works. Floating it left, in conjuction with the already floated left `maincontent` will position it the way you intend it too - in a much more semantic manner.

Comment: Also, the fact that Chrome is showing `sidebar` as within `maincontent` is possibly due to the unclosed `div` that is mentioned in the validator.

Comment: Russell, re: "I'm not sure why... etc" This would be purely down to ignorance / error on my part. Wish I could find this div.

Comment: This probably means nothing at all, but when I copy the source out and do a search on "<div" and "</div", I get the same number of opens and closes. This is going to drive me crazy. I followed your suggestion and changed sidebar to float: left; and now it displays fine in Chrome, but the background image for the #page element is missing in FF...

Comment: Odd. When I float it left in FF via Firebug the background image is left untouched.

Comment: aha ahahahaha. background image now displaying properly in both, but sidebar pushed beneath maincontent in FF. aha ahaha.

Comment: Make sure that `sidebar` is *not* in `maincontent` but rather beneath it. (Could be the unclosed `</div>` issue)

Comment: I'm as certain as I can be that that's where it now exists (as in, I explicitly shifted it below the maincontent div). I don't know why the validator is saying there's an unclosed div -- i have the same number of div openings as I have closings, and I used Google Chrome's element inspector to manually go through and delete all the divs one by one and was left with nothing unmatched.

Comment: Thanks also to you Russell -- I feel better knowing I'm using a float to place the sidebar, and your helpfulness was very appreciated.